# What job description should I give to my designer for custom icons and graphics for my new website?

Tags: website-design, icon

I am in the middle of redesigning my website. As part of my website, I'm looking to get custom graphics done relating to my product value proposition and features.

How/What do I tell the designer to get this kind of graphics done for my new website. I need the icons to remain consistent and have animation on the mouse over (only when icons are placed on the website). Icons need to be both static version and animated version.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems obvious but can't you merely show the designer the samples you've posted here?

Comment: You should probably be talking to your designer not us.

Comment: Animations/interactivity such as mouse-over states will require CSS coding. Icons are just image files, they don't have any interactivity on their own.